# i want to round a double variable into two decimals only

Tags: java

how can i round a double variables in java into only two decimals?

Comment: Do you want a string or a double result?

Comment: Check the below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/22646612/4082061

http://stackoverflow.com/q/153724/4082061

Answer (score 0):

yourNewFormatedDouble = new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(yourOldDoubleHere);

Comment: where this syntax must be written in my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
String result = df.format(myDouble);
```